# horizontal alignment <input> and <table>

Tags: html

I have following code with some input fields and a calculator. Want to align them horizontal on my website, on the mobile version they sould be aligned vertical. I attached some images for illustration.

The problem is maybe, that there is more then one table and in combination with input fields. I tried a lot of edits in the code, but can not solve it. So I attached the initial code, which I tried to modify.
I am beginner and really appreciate your support!

[image]

[image]

```css
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="zxx">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>rechner</title>




<title>rechner</title>


<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
some js
</script>
</head>
<img src="images/calc.png">
<body>
<div style="margin-left: 50px;">
<p></p>
<h3>   abc</h3>

<div align="left">
<div id="calclpayment">
        <form>
        <strong>
          <br />
   Bitte folgende Felder ergänzen:</strong> <br />
<br />
<table width="100%" align="left">
          <td width="50"><div align="left">   def/Monat</div></td>
              <td width="40"><input type= "text" size="6" name="def"  /></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><div align="left">   Anzahl defe</div></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="6" name="defe" />&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="40"></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="24"><div align="left">   + Lohnbuchhaltung:</div></td>
        <td><div align="left">
          <select name="lbh">
            <option value=1>Ja</option>
            <option value=0>Nein</option>
          </select>
        </div></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="24"><div align="left">   + defeer/MwSt:</div></td>
        <td><div align="left">
          <select name="steuer">
            <option value=1>Ja</option>
            <option value=0>Nein</option>
          </select>
        </div></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="24"><div align="left">   + eingeschränkte defeere</div></td>
        <td><div align="left">
          <select name="rev">
            <option value=1>Ja</option>
            <option value=0>Nein</option>
          </select>
        </div></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="24"><div align="left">   + Jahresabschluss</div></td>
        <td><div align="left">
          <select name="jr">
            <option value=1>Ja</option>
            <option value=0>Nein</option>
          </select>
        </div></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="Input" type="button" value="Preis berechnen" onclick="calcpayments()"/></td>
      </tr>
          </table>
   <br />
  <b>  text718:</b>  <br />
  <br />

  <div id="monthlypayment" style="font-size: 25px;background-color:#1b365d;
font-weight: bold; width: 150px; padding: 5px; color:#FFF;" > 0  </div>
      </form>

  </div>
          <br />
          <br />
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<h3><p style="text-align:center">Für deine Berechnungen zu Diensten!</p></h3>

                      <!-- Calculator Start Here -->
          <head>
     <script>
     some js
     </script>
     <!-- for styling -->
     <style>

    .spec  .title{
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        text-align:center;
        width: 210px;
        color:#1b365d;
        }

    .spec    input[type="button"]
        {
        background-color:#1b365d;
        color: white;
        border: solid black 2px;
        width:100%
        }

    .spec     input[type="text"]
        {
        background-color:white;
        border: solid black 2px;
        text-align:right;
        width:100%;
        height:45px
        }
  .spec      .center {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        }
      }
     </style>
  </head>

  <!-- create table -->

  <body>
<div class = "spec" >
     <div class = title ></div>
     <table border="1" class="center">
        <tr>
           <td colspan="3"><input type="text" id="result"/></td>
           <!-- clr() function will call clr to clear all value -->
           <td><input type="button" value="c" onclick="clr()"/></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
           <!-- create button and assign value to each button -->
           <!-- dis("1") will call function dis to display value -->
           <td><input type="button" value="1" onclick="dis('1')"/> </td>
           <td><input type="button" value="2" onclick="dis('2')"/> </td>
           <td><input type="button" value="3" onclick="dis('3')"/> </td>
           <td><input type="button" value="/" onclick="dis('/')"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><input type="button" value="4" onclick="dis('4')"/> </td>
           <td><input type="button" value="5" onclick="dis('5')"/> </td>
           <td><input type="button" value="6" onclick="dis('6')"/> </td>
           <td><input type="button" value="-" onclick="dis('-')"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><input type="button" value="7" onclick="dis('7')"/> </td>
           <td><input type="button" value="8" onclick="dis('8')"/> </td>
           <td><input type="button" value="9" onclick="dis('9')"/> </td>
           <td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="dis('+')"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><input type="button" value="." onclick="dis('.')"/> </td>
           <td><input type="button" value="0" onclick="dis('0')"/> </td>
           <!-- solve function call function solve to evaluate value -->
           <td><input type="button" value="=" onclick="solve()"/> </td>
           <td><input type="button" value="x" onclick="dis('*')"/> </td>
        </tr>

     </table>
</div>
  </body>

</div>
</div>
<p></p>
```

Comment: I don't quite get the question, let's see if I do. The first picture is how you want the three elements to be placed on desktop and the second picture is how you want the three elements to be placed on mobile. Correct?

Comment: that's correct! :)

Comment: your code is pretty messed up.  Start by only having 1 set of body tags.  use w3 validator service to check your html.  then come back with a revised question. What you want to do is pretty easy using flexbox

Comment: thanks for your feedback! I am no professional coder, and spent already too much time for such a "simple" optimization.. I checked the w3 validator there are 37 errors.. Would be really nice, if someone is willing to help. if not, I will have to hire a professional dev. to get it finished.

Comment: @arbess your work is pretty sloppy.  If you want help put more effort into your work

Comment: Ok, what I would suggest is to replace your layout with flexbox. Flexbox would make it very easy to achieve what you're trying to do. But before I give a suggestion, can you create a Fiddle or Codepen? So we can see the actual problem completely before we can give a solution?

Answer (score 1):

if i get the right meaning, here are my suggestions

1. try to use the "float" in css?

such as the float: left and float: right

and here is a example:

```
<html class="no-js" lang="zxx">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>rechner</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="images/calc.png">
        <div style="margin-left: 50px;">
            <p></p>
            <h3> abc</h3>
        </div>
        <div align="left">
            <div id="calclpayment" style="float:right">
                <form>
                    <strong>
                        <br />
                        Bitte folgende Felder ergänzen:</strong> <br />
                    <br />
                    <table width="100%" align="left">
                        <td width="50">
                            <div align="left"> def/Monat</div>
                        </td>
                        <td width="40"><input type="text" size="6" name="def" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div align="left"> Anzahl defe</div>
                            </td>
                            <td><input type="text" size="6" name="defe" />&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="40"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="24">
                                <div align="left"> + Lohnbuchhaltung:</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div align="left">
                                    <select name="lbh">
                                        <option value=1>Ja</option>
                                        <option value=0>Nein</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="24">
                                <div align="left"> + defeer/MwSt:</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div align="left">
                                    <select name="steuer">
                                        <option value=1>Ja</option>
                                        <option value=0>Nein</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="24">
                                <div align="left"> + eingeschränkte defeere</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div align="left">
                                    <select name="rev">
                                        <option value=1>Ja</option>
                                        <option value=0>Nein</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="24">
                                <div align="left"> + Jahresabschluss</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div align="left">
                                    <select name="jr">
                                        <option value=1>Ja</option>
                                        <option value=0>Nein</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><input name="Input" type="button" value="Preis berechnen" onclick="calcpayments()" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <br />
                    <b> text718:</b> <br />
                    <br />

                    <div id="monthlypayment" style="font-size: 25px;background-color:#1b365d;
font-weight: bold; width: 150px; padding: 5px; color:#FFF;">
                        0 </div>
                </form>

            </div>

            <h3>
                <p style="text-align:center">Für deine Berechnungen zu Diensten!</p>
            </h3>

            <!-- Calculator Start Here -->
                <script>
                    //some js
     </script>
                <!-- for styling -->
                <style>

                    .spec  .title{
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        text-align:center;
        width: 210px;
        color:#1b365d;
        }

    .spec    input[type="button"]
        {
        background-color:#1b365d;
        color: white;
        border: solid black 2px;
        width:100%
        }

    .spec     input[type="text"]
        {
        background-color:white;
        border: solid black 2px;
        text-align:right;
        width:100%;
        height:45px
        }
  .spec      .center {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        }
      }
     </style>

            <!-- create table -->
            <div class="spec" style="float:left">
                <div class=title></div>
                <table border="1" class="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"><input type="text" id="result" /></td>
                        <!-- clr() function will call clr to clear all value -->
                        <td><input type="button" value="c" onclick="clr()" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <!-- create button and assign value to each button -->
                        <!-- dis("1") will call function dis to display value -->
                        <td><input type="button" value="1" onclick="dis('1')" /> </td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="2" onclick="dis('2')" /> </td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="3" onclick="dis('3')" /> </td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="/" onclick="dis('/')" /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" value="4" onclick="dis('4')" /> </td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="5" onclick="dis('5')" /> </td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="6" onclick="dis('6')" /> </td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="-" onclick="dis('-')" /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" value="7" onclick="dis('7')" /> </td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="8" onclick="dis('8')" /> </td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="9" onclick="dis('9')" /> </td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="dis('+')" /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" value="." onclick="dis('.')" /> </td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="0" onclick="dis('0')" /> </td>
                        <!-- solve function call function solve to evaluate value -->
                        <td><input type="button" value="=" onclick="solve()" /> </td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="x" onclick="dis('*')" /> </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

2. use 2 html files, one for website and one for mobile and use javascript to jump

and use margin to fit the position